# How to fix the problem about at('@') path can't find module when unit test on vueJS

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I met a problem. I have a component:

```js
<template>
  <span :class="lightClassName">
    <i class="fas fa-circle markIcon" />
  </span>
</template>

<script>
import { EnumAttendanceStatuses } from "@/enums";

export default {
  // ...some code
}
</script>
```

And I want to write unit test for it:

```js
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import AttendanceStatusLight from "./AttendanceStatusLight.vue";

test("AttendanceStatusLight", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(AttendanceStatusLight);

  console.log(wrapper);
});
```

But when I execute the test file, console print the error:

[image]

I am really wonder know that how do I fix the problem! Thanks any answer and comment!

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `@` with `~`

```
<template>
  <span :class="lightClassName">
    <i class="fas fa-circle markIcon" />
  </span>
</template>

<script>
import { EnumAttendanceStatuses } from "~/enums";

export default {
  // ...some code
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your [Jest config's `moduleNameMapper`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) to map the `@` path alias to your `src` directory:

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  }
}
```

Consider using [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) with the Jest plugin, where this is already configured in the [preset](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/791fa28/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/default/jest-preset.js#L25-L27).